# I have a problem with the cloth animation

Tags: cloth-simulation

[image]

Somehow my cloth-simulation seems to pull the clothes inside although I have applied a collision modifier at the fair underneath

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/media/d/5/d52096cda19fe603568499ee547a4e4e.blend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the coat and put the *Armature* modifier above the *Cloth* modifier:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!